# Column count element overlaps to next column

Tags: html, css, column-count

```css
.main{
  column-count: 2;
}

.main .list{
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.main .list:hover{
  background: #11e;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main">
 <li class="list">list-item-1</li>
 <li class="list">list-item-2</li>
 <li class="list">list-item-3</li>
 <li class="list">list-item-4</li>
 <li class="list">list-item-5</li>
 <li class="list">list-item-6</li>
 <li class="list">list-item-7</li>
</ul>
```

When I hover on the `list-item-4` I can see the hover color covers some section on the second column as well. How can fix it?

Comment: Yeah what Mike said, use break-inside: avoid; on the li tag

Comment: Sure, let me try that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `break-inside: avoid;` to prevent the experienced behaviour.

You do not need to use vendor prefixes as usage of `break-inside` is already supported by more than 99% of the browsers according to [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=break-inside)

Please have a look at my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/480q1boe/) to see it working.